# Is it possible move a storyboard item from compact - regular to any - any?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard, xib

In Xcode 6 Beta 5 is it possible move a storyboard item from compact - regular to any - any? I see them only in light grey and I can't use them.

[image: Screenshot of light grey elements]

Comment: The only way I have found so far is to copy/delete the item in compact/regular and paste it into any/any.

Comment: Idem but it is absurd O-o

Comment: Copying and pasting seems the only was at the moment, though I'm sure they will improve on this. Bear in mind that copying the items over, only copies SOME of the constrains which is incredibly annoying.

Comment: I'm agree with you, will see if something change in beta 6 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way, in beta 5, is (as told by zisoft) to copy/delete the item in compact/regular and paste it into any/any.

Comment: Is this still the only way?

Comment: I believe this is still the only way, as of Xcode 7.3

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue and managed to quickly fix this from storyboard source. They key is storyboard uses an "exclusion" strategy to ignore elements in specific sizes and those are quite easy to delete.
Instructions:

- Right click your storyboard file -> Open as -> Source code
- Search (cmd+f) for "`variation`" elements inside the source. Those elements contain a list of elements (`exclude` tags) to be ignored by each Size Class(`key` tags). One illustrative sample:

> ```
> <variation key="default">
>     <mask key="subviews">
>         <exclude reference="B88-52-VvO"/>
>     </mask>
>     <mask key="constraints">
>         <exclude reference="tCi-fC-2oS"/>
>         <exclude reference="XOf-O6-9Wn"/>
>     </mask>
> </variation>
>     <mask key="subviews">
>         <exclude reference="B88-52-VvO"/>
>     </mask>
>     <mask key="constraints">
>         <exclude reference="tCi-fC-2oS"/>
>         <exclude reference="XOf-O6-9Wn"/>
>     </mask>
> </variation>
> ```

- If as me, you just messed things up adding something while being outside of default "any-any" and just want to move all your views back to any-any, it is as simple as delete all the variation elements so everything will be available in all views.

**Note** that, as I tried to explain, this will make all elements available in all the layouts so this is only suitable if this is your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Open the storyboard as source code
Search for the keyword variation key="heightClass=regular-widthClass=compact" and replace it with variation key="default"

[image]